# Sort 3 integers that the user inputed in MIPS

Tags: sorting, mips, cpu-registers

Hey guys I am new to MIPS programming and an having a hard time grasping the syntax and rules of MIPS.  I am trying to write a program that takes user input for 3 integers and sorts them from least to greatest.  So far the code that I have is

```
.data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter an integer: "

.text
.global main

main:
li $v0, 4
la $a3, prompt
syscall

li $v0, 5
li $a0, $v0
syscall

li $v0, 5
li $a1, $v0
syscall

li $v0, 5
li $a2, $v0
syscall
```

I am confused as to how to take input and store them into 3 seperate registers $a0-$a2.
Also, I have no idea how to declare a function with parameters.  I would also like to know if the above code for gathering user input is correct because I think i am doing something wrong here.  I am not used to this low level language but am pretty fluent in Java.  Any explanations can be made in terms of Java if that helps to simplify it.  Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Several points here:

`li` is for loading immediates. You probably want `move` for two registers. You don't have to load 5 three times.

To print a string you load the string into $a0.

If you are fluent in Java a sorting algorithm should be no problem. You don't even need a function.

A function uses `jal` to save a return address and go to a function using $a0-$a3 registers. You should look up a tutorial on this if you don't know how it works.

Comment: Thanks for responding. I have to have a function because that's what my professor wants.  I know how to sort in java but I have no clue how to translate it into MIPS language.  Can you give me an example of a MIPS sorting algorithm?  Thanks in advance

Comment: @Heyya I'm not certain, but since you only have 3 numbers sorting should be fairly trivial. You could probably get away with a few swaps (a very minimal version of bubble sort).